# What is the relevance of the snow "speech bubble" in Winter Bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012, logo

On the Winter Bash site, the logo has a "speech bubble"> This isn't present instantly but is slowly built up over a few minutes as the snow falls.

[image]

Is this just for aesthetics or does it have a higher purpose (such as triggering a secret hat)?

Comment: -1 for no animated gif =P

Comment: Me, I’m trying to figure out how to win the video game of chasing the snowflakes with your mouse. Your mouse imposes a bit of anti-gravity/repulsion on a vector straight up from it, which sends the snowflakes up up and away.

Comment: @tchrist *Control* is important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the [Stack Exchange logo/mascot](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/meet-bubbles/), Bubbles. As far as I know, it is just an easter egg and does not grant a secret hat.

Comment: Ah, I see it now!

Comment: It's not even an Easter Egg is it?  I mean, it shows up fairly quickly.  I'd consider it an intro animation at best.  Now the purple unicorn, **that's** an Easter Egg.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas what purple unicorn?!?

Comment: @AustinHenley If I told you, then it wouldn't be much of a secret, would it?  But see the conversation [here](https://twitter.com/jzy/status/282211112278179840), [here](https://twitter.com/wax_eagle/status/282215431899582464) and [here](https://twitter.com/jzy/status/282215615215828992).

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas cough cough cough  [go here...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash/161334#161334)