# The snow "Quote Bubble" is back, is the snow unicorn too?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013, unicorns, easter-eggs

Last year, there was a [snow speech / quote bubble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160241/what-is-the-relevance-of-the-snow-speech-bubble-in-winter-bash) that showed up on the Winterbash page if you left it a while / played with the mouse in the right way. I've noticed that this year it's back:

[image: Snow bubble]

Last year also saw the [winter unicorn appear for some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash). Is the unicorn back too? And/or are there hints in the JS that it may return?

Comment: I guess so, because the blank space on the left of the text *Winter Bash* is a link, just like the *snow quote bubble*(of course its not displayed) but may be the left side Unicorn may come up if you wait for some more time, patiently.

Comment: Last year the snow flakes were attracted to you though - this time they're scared off by your mouse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The snow unicorn is a rare and unpredictable creature. We couldn't lure it back to our JavaScripty lands this year. We'll always cherish the memory of last year's sighting, though.

Comment: I've been reloading that page and waiting repeatedly _all week_ and _now you tell me there's no unicorn?_ I am totally blaming you during Trello review today for getting nothing otherwise done.

Comment: @TinyTim Why would you assume we'd ever do something the exact same way twice? :)

Comment: @Laura - have you tried with a monkey? Not any monkey - one that has been dipped in grease...

Answer (score 6):

Searching for it, I  tried to ask some mod on the Tavern if they can confirm the existence of an egg but without much luck.

A quick inspection of the js code for the page shows nothing suspicious. Also, I have tried every key combo that come to mind to gather the snow, but again nothing worked.

Will update if I find out something.

**Edit**: just some random fact.

In my original question from the last year (the one quoted in the question above) I made a reference to Twilight Sparkle begin the unicorn in the snow.

This year we have an unicorn hat. Also, somebody found THIS in the hat sprite sheet.... go figure.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I searched the `home.js` file for some of the same bits of code that appears in the answer [here about last year's unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash), and sadly, I couldn't find the same code. This is rather difficult because of the minification, so I could be wrong, but either the code to display the unicorn has changed, or it will manifest itself other ways (like @SPArchaeologist mentioned).